# What is the best survey method to use for conducting an annual risk and fraud survey?

Tags: survey

I have been assigned the task of conducting an annual risk and fraud survey at work. I have a limited statistical background and am not sure what the best way to approach this is. The goal of the survey is to measure the concerns of upper management in different areas that represent risk to the company and also measure stress levels and other factors that can lead to fraud. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what surveying method would create the most accurate responses given my survey goals?  I am considering a Likert-Scale questionnaire…

The group size will be ~120 people with an anticipated response rate of 95%. The survey will be conducted through sharepoint on our intranet.

Comment: This question leads me to believe that you should hire someone to help you. Survey data is generally garbage in garbage out. DIY surveys are usually only directional at best.

Comment: I totally agree with Brandon. When you have worked even a little bit in the area, you'd be surprised how easy it is to screw up, and how difficult it is to write good questions that generate meaningful answers (there are techniques to improve the questions, though). You would want to find a local statistical consultant who has expertise in survey research. Most large universities in the US would have statistical consulting units or centers, although not all of them would have the required expertise; I am not sure about how this is done in other countries.

Answer (score 6):

1. Operationalize what you mean by stress. Maybe have a question asking about stress experienced by x or fatigue attributed to y. Having each response on a likert scale is appropriate for these types of questions.
2. As far as areas that represent risk to the company- if it is categorical data you wish to collect then allowing a respondent to select one of a set of categories is appropriate.
3. Other areas. An open-ended question where respondents can write their views is appropriate.